# windows.web.http and ByteArray

Tags: c#, web-services, arrays, windows-phone-8.1, dotnet-httpclient

I was using `System.net.http` in my Windows Phone 8.1 app until I got an issue with self-signed and untrusted certificates.

Then now, I'm using the `Windows.Web.Http` framework. Everything works well EXCEPT that I can't find an equivalent to the `ByteArrayContent`in the `IHttpContent` interface. In the same way, `IHttpContent` has no method equivalent for `ReadAsByteArrayAsync`.

I was using `ByteArrayContent` and `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` for sending and getting file through HttpClient.

What's the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `HttpBufferContent` and `IHttpContent.ReadAsBufferAsync()`.

With the WinRT extensions you can convert an array to `IBuffer` calling `myArray.AsBuffer()`.

```
// using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
byte[] foo = new byte[] { 20, 21, 22, 23 };
IHttpContent content = new HttpBufferContent(foo.AsBuffer());

// using Windows.Storage.Streams;
IBuffer barBuffer = await content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
byte[] bararray = barBuffer.ToArray();
```